# set id in value field of select option in react.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, onchange

I have a `tblGender` table in database having 3 fields `fldID`, `fldName` and `isActive`. `tblEmployee` table has a foreign key referring to `fldID` of `tblGender`. Now I am fetching a gender list from the database and setting it as follows:

Fetching Data:

```
fetch('api/Employee/GetGenders')
            .then(response => response.json() as Promise<Array<any>>)
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ genderList: data });
            });
```

Populating Dropdown:

```
<select className="form-control" data-val="true" name="FldGender" defaultValue={this.state.empData.FldGender} onChange={e => this.state.empData.FldGender = e.target.value} required>
                            <option value="">-- Select Gender --</option>
                            {this.state.genderList.map(gender =>
                                <option key={gender.fldID} value={gender.fldID}>{gender.fldName}</option>
                            )}
                        </select>
```

but `gender.fldID` is not set in the value. Now if I try to set `gender.fldName` it is successfully set. But I want to get `gender.fldID` whenever the dropdown is changed. How can I set the `fldID` and not the `fldName` in the `this.state.empData.FldGender`'s `onChange` event?

Comment: can you add a sample data for your `genderList` ?

Comment: This is the data fetched in genderList:                                                                              
0: {fldId: 1, fldName: "Male", isActive: true, tblEmployees: Array(0)}
1: {fldId: 3, fldName: "Female", isActive: true, tblEmployees: Array(0)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo . You genderList data has `fldId` but in your code you have mentioned it as `fldID` . Please change your option as below

```
<option key={gender.fldId} value={gender.fldId}>{gender.fldName}</option>
```